# div layout on top of an image within an expanding div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to layout some content (an icon on the left, heading and text on the right) on top of an image which sits within an expanding div.  I'm mainly doing this to see if it can be done but would be nice if I can make it functional.  I stitched the functionality together from a couple of tutorials but can't find anything online on how to finish it off.

I'm struggling to layout the div on top of the wave image.

[kind of see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/r3dg3cko/D4J9H/3/)

I've laid it out in a table so you can see roughly how I need it, I'm guessing I need to float to lay the divs out but can't get it to work.  any help would be most appreciated.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .grow {
        height: 200px;
        width: 499px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        transition: height 0.5s;
        -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
        background-image: url(images/passmembers/test/sunset.jpg);
    }
    .grow:hover {
        height: 300px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="grow" );>
        <div id="container">
            <img src="images/passmembers/test/wave.png">
            <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: #FFF; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <table width="499px">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="239" align="left" valign="bottom">
                            <img src="images/passmembers/test/icon.png" width="75" height="75">
                        </td>
                        <td width="248">
                            <p><strong>Hot Deals</strong></p>
                            <p>Hot Deals, Hot DealsHot Deals, Hot DealsHot Deals, Hot Deals</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please set up something on jsfiddle so we can see what you're talking about, rather than trying to imagine it. But this line is likely one source of your problems:

`<div class="grow" ); position: relative;>`

Comment: Thanks, I've not used jsfiddle before so apologies for the mess but you get the idea.  the wave element doesn't work in it but does on a page. Thanks for pointing out the duplication that worked so I just need to lay out the div on top now.

http://jsfiddle.net/r3dg3cko/D4J9H/3/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you solved the problem by your own.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D4J9H/7/

When using the JSFiddle, there's a textfield for the HTML content, a textfield for the CSS and a textfield for the Javascript code. You wrote everything in the CSS textfield, that's why the result wasn't what you expected.

HTML:

```
<div class="grow" style="position:relative;">
    <div id="container">
        <img src="http://i128.photobucket.com/albums/p195/R3DG3CKO/wave.png">
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; margin: 0px; text-align: center; color: #FFF; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
            <table width="499px">
                <tr>
                    <td width="239" align="left" valign="bottom">
                        <img src="http://i128.photobucket.com/albums/p195/R3DG3CKO/icon.png" width="75" height="75">
                    </td>
                    <td width="248">
                        <p><strong>Hot Deals</strong>
                        </p>
                        <p>Hot Deals, Hot DealsHot Deals, Hot DealsHot Deals, Hot Deals</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.grow {
    height: 200px;
    width: 499px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    transition: height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s;
    background-image: url(http://i128.photobucket.com/albums/p195/R3DG3CKO/sunset.jpg);
}
.grow:hover {
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll get there slowly.  What I want to do is replace the table with a div layout?

Comment: awesome, thanks - yours has the strange spacing at the bottom as well though, I've had this in a few places.  What's causing it?

Comment: the `<img>` tag under `#container` needs a `display:block;`.
http://jsfiddle.net/D4J9H/11/
`<img>` tags have a default `display:inline;` and that's why it has a weird behavior.